# auto completion of slds classes is not working on Aura and LWC

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, slds, vs-code, autocomplete

Auto-suggestion of SLDS classes is not working in Aura and LWC after adding SLDS validator extension in VS Code. Please help me.[image]